# MySQL INSERT DELAYED - How to find out when inserts are done

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

When using MySQL's INSERT DELAYED statements, is there a way to force all Inserts to execute before continuing? Or alternatively to find out whether the Inserts are done yet?

Comment: If you want the rows to be inserted before continuing, why are you using the delayed clause?

Comment: @Lasse, that may still make sense if there is a noticeable period of time between the `insert-delayed` and the next action that necessitates the test.

Comment: **DELAYED inserts and replaces were deprecated in MySQL 5.6**. **In MySQL 5.7, DELAYED is not supported**. The server recognizes but ignores the DELAYED keyword, handles the insert as a nondelayed insert, and generates an ER_WARN_LEGACY_SYNTAX_CONVERTED warning (“INSERT DELAYED is no longer supported. The statement was converted to INSERT”). The DELAYED keyword is scheduled for removal in a future release. Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-delayed.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find out by doing a

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Not_flushed_delayed_rows'
```

For for more info

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE '%delay%'
```

Note that `INSERT DELAYED` has a few issues you need to be aware of please read the first link below for more info.

```
FLUSH TABLES
```

Will force an immediate insert of the delayed rows.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html
and: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-status.html

Comment: As of MySQL 5.6.6, INSERT DELAYED is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release. Use INSERT (without DELAYED) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you need to know when they are completed, why to mark them DELAYED?

Also, using these can be dangerous for example because

> Pending INSERT DELAYED statements are
>   lost if a table is write locked and
>   ALTER TABLE is used to modify the
>   table structure.

To force all DELAYED statements to execute, call `FLUSH TABLES`.

[Manual link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html).

Comment: >Well, if you need to know when they are completed, why to mark them DELAYED? - I know this seems illogical, please bear with me...

Comment: @jms, don't worry about the comments, `INSERT DELAY` only works with engines which don't support transactions (MyISAM etc), so your data is not secure against inconsistency anyway. If you've got vital data use an engine with transaction support like InnoDB.